# How do I specify the feature columns in tf.estimator.DNNClassifier?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a dataset that looks basically like this

```
FeatureA FeatureB FeatureC Target

3        2        5        1

4        1        8        0

3        0        2        0
```

The target is categorical (1,0), features are numerical. The goal is to learn an algorithm to classify based on all 3 features whether target is 0 or 1.

When calling the classifier e.g. on the Google colab's example on building a text classifier, they have written the code as such

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
hidden_units=[500, 100],
feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
n_classes=2,
optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003))
```

However, in my example, where I just want to use the 3 feature columns as `feature_columns`, how do I tell `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` that? I.e. what do I pass into the argument `feature_columns`?

Answer (score 0):

Its actually quite simple...though it took me a while to understand it.

Take a close look this code below:

```
# Represent a tf.float64 scalar.
numeric_feature_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="SepalLength",
                                                          dtype=tf.float64)
```

One can say that you are "building" a column for this particular model. In this scenario, the column name is  "SepalLength" and its data type is float64.

Lets apply it to your scenario:

```
numeric_feature_column_1 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="_1",
                                                          dtype=tf.float64)

numeric_feature_column_2 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="_2",
                                                          dtype=tf.float64)

numeric_feature_column_3 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="_3",
                                                          dtype=tf.float64)

estimator   = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
              hidden_units=[500, 100],
              feature_columns=[numeric_feature_column_1,
                               numeric_feature_column_2,
                               numeric_feature_column_3],
              n_classes=2,
              optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003)
              )
```

I strongly recommend that you read these links below to get a better understanding of Tensorflow's data pipeline and how it connects to the Estimator class.

- https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets
- https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns
- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/numeric_column
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/estimator/trainer/model.py

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it but I got this error ValueError: Feature _1 is not in features dictionary. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000);

Comment: Your train_input_fn should output values with same names as your column names

Comment: thanks so much. my train_input_fn is train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    training_examples, training_targets["ecoli"], num_epochs=None, shuffle=True) where training_examples is just a dataframe with columns that have variable names, and training_targets is training_examples with an addition column 'ecoli' which is the classification target. I've had a look at the function https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/pandas_input_fn but it doesn't shed any light on that. Apologies.

Comment: Are your column names in the dataframe the same as your tensorflow columns?

Comment: I suggest posting your code in your question so it will be easier for people to help you

Comment: Thanks so much. I will post my code. How do I check the column names for the tensorflow columns?

Comment: If your pandas dataframe has a column named "SepalLength" then your tensorflow column should be setup like this:
`numeric_feature_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="SepalLength",
                                                          dtype=tf.float64)`

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry for the late reply. It works, but I have an issue with the target being a rare event, so difficult to classify. Many thanks for your help though - how do I 'upvote' you on stack overflow?

Comment: Actually, you should see a green check mark around my post.